# Are these two versions of Sobolev embedding related?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

In Griffith-Harris Section 0.6 we have this Sobolev lemma:

> Let $H_s$ be the space of formal Fourier series $u(x):=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z^n}u_ke^{i(k,x)}$ on $(\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z)^n$ such that the $H_s$ norm $\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z^n}(1+|k|^2)|u_k|^2$ is finite. Then
> $$H_{s+[n/2]+1}\subset C^s(T),$$
> i.e. every $u \in H_{s+[n/2]+1}$ is the Fourier series of some $s$ times differentiable $\phi$ on $T$. Moreover, such series converges uniformly.

On the other hand, I have seen this version of Sobolev Embedding, concerning the usual Sobolev space $W^{s,2}$ defined using weak derivative and $L^2$ norms:

> If $n<2s$ and $1/2-s/n=-r/n$ then $W^{s,2}(\mathbb R^n)\subset C^r(\mathbb R^n)$.

The only relation between $W^{s,2}$ and $H_s$ I know is that, we can naturally embed $C^s$ into $H_s$, on which the $H_s$ and $W^{s,2}$ norms are equivalent. My question is, are the two versions of Sobolev embedding above related? Can we use the second one above to prove the first one? Thanks.

Comment: By definition, $H^s(\Omega)=W^{s,2}(\Omega)$. Apparently the two versions are different mostly because the underlying set is different: $T$ and $\mathbb R$, respectively.